# How to load a JSON file and convert it to an object of a specific type?

Tags: json, powershell, deserialization, powershell-3.0

I have a type `FooObject` and I have a JSON file which was serialized from a `FooObject` instance. Now I want to use `ConvertFrom-Json` to load the JSON file to memory and covert the output of the command to a `FooObject` object, and then use the new object in a cmdlet `Set-Bar` which only accept `FooObject` as the parameter type.

But I notice that the output type of `ConvertFrom-Json` is `PSCustomObject` and I did not find any way to convert `PSCustomObject` to `FooObject`.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Try casting the custom object to `FooObject`:

```
$foo = [FooObject](Get-Content 'C:\path\to\your.json' | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json)
```

If that doesn't work, try constructing the `FooObject` instance with the properties of the input object (provided the class has a constructor like that):

```
$json = Get-Content 'C:\path\to\your.json' | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json
$foo = New-Object FooObject ($json.Foo, $json.Bar, $json.Baz)
```

If that also doesn't work you need to create an empty `FooObject` instance and update its properties afterwards:

```
$json = Get-Content 'C:\path\to\your.json' | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json
$foo = New-Object FooObject
$foo.AA = $json.Foo
$foo.BB = $json.Bar
$foo.CC = $json.Baz
```

Comment: Since I own the code of `Set-Bar` (in C#). Is it possible I make it accept `PSCustomObject` and convert it to `FooObject` internally? Which will be the better way for my cmdlet user?

Comment: Should be possible if you change the interface to accept `PSCustomObject` or `Object`. I'm not too familiar with C#, though.

Comment: You should be using ```Get-Content -Raw 'C:\path\to\your.json'``` to load your json content

Answer (score 21):

Based on [PowerTip: Convert JSON File to PowerShell Object](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-convert-json-file-to-powershell-object/), you can do the following:

```
Get-Content -Raw -Path <jsonFile>.json | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Comment: Even shorter: `Get-Content <jsonFile> | ConvertFrom-Json`

Comment: How does this convert JSON to a _specific_ type if the type is not specified? 

Answer (score 7):

I realize this is an old post, but I found a more efficient way of doing this, if casting it doesn't work. Definitely try casting it first. Casting will work as long as your class doesn't contain nested collections of custom types. Say your class looks like the following.

```
class Container 
{
    [string] $Id
    [string] $Name
    [System.Collections.Generic.List[Process]] $Processes
}
class Process
{
    [string] $Id
    [string] $Name
}
```

ConvertFrom-Json would convert it to a [PSCustomObject] but would make the List[Process] into an Object[] which would cause any cast operation to throw the following exception.

> Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Process]".
>
> ConvertToFinalInvalidCastException

Use the following to deserialize this type of hierarchy.

```
$serializer = [System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer]::new()

$content = $serializer.Deserialize((Get-Content -Path $JsonFilePath), [YourCustomType])
```

The **[System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer]** is how **ConvertFrom-Json** works in the background. So, I just created a new instance of that and was able to convert a multi-level (*four levels to be exact and each level had a collection of the level below it*) json file into my powershell class easily. I also realize that this could be simplified into the following, but it is easier to read above.

```
$content = [System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer]::new().Deserialize((Get-Content -Path $JsonFilePath), [YourCustomType])
```

Comment: When trying to use this approach, I was met with:

> Could not load type 'System.Web.UI.WebResourceAttribute' from assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

This was after adding both `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web` and `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web.Extensions`

Comment: I'm not sure about that @KristianWilliams . I never had to add the types to my session. It should already be available if you can use `ConvertFrom-Json`. Like I said in my answer, that is the assembly that cmdlet uses. So, you shouldn't need to add the type.